# Divmod alternative method

Tags: python

i was looking for questions of converting bases and i came upon a solution on here using divmod. the code looked like this.

```
    integer = 0
for character in innitvar:
    assert character in SY2VA, 'Found unknown character!'
    value = SY2VA[character]
    assert value < basevar, 'Found digit outside base!'
    integer *= basevar
    integer += value


array = []
while integer:
    integer, value = divmod(integer, convertvar)
    array.append(VA2SY[value])
answer = ''.join(reversed(array))
```

the nice person describe some methodology on how the divmod was being used based on remainder and whole numbers, but i was wondering if anyone had an alternative way of doing this without divmod so that i could understand it more clearly. I guess im also asking if it is possible to do this without the use of divmod.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

```
integer, value = divmod(integer, base)
```

is equivalent to

```
value = integer % base
integer //= base
```

Does that help?  Maybe with a temp variable, and longer-winded:

```
temp = integer // base
value = integer - temp * base
integer = temp
```

Picture it for a power-of-10 base, say, `base = 100`.  Then starting with 12345,

```
integer, value = divmod(12345, 100)
```

yields `integer = 123` and `value = 45`.  That is, `divmod(whatever, 100)` peels off the last two digits as the 2nd returned value, delivers the rest of the digits as its first returned value.

Comment: Thank you! this definitely helps me understand it better and implement it without divmod! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do the division and modulus operations separately.

```
def int2str(integer, base):
    digits = []
    while integer:
        value = integer % base
        integer = integer / base
        digits.append(dictionary[value])
    return ''.join(reversed(digits))
```